# Copy 20GB to FTP

Tags: ftp, backup

I need to copy 20GB of files to FTP server from one machine, on which I have SSH access.
I tried midnight commander, but it failed - segmentation fault.

So I tried to use curlftpfs and just copy it, but it stopped after 650MB. Maybe timeout?

What you recommend to do?

Comment: I recommend finding another protocol.

Comment: Why don't you split the files into 100MB each, and upload with FileZilla for example? (hence it can continue if the upload fails/disconnects)

Comment: Is it an option to use physical media, to get the files elsewhere? It may be faster to send 1 or a few USB keys in the mail...

Comment: WinSCP and PSFTP both support resume. Also, you should be able to resume broken uploads using rsync as well if the server has it enabled.

Comment: If you have SSH access, why not scp or rsync?

Comment: I need to copy 20GB of files.. Not only 1 file. It's full of images. I can't use physical media. I will try rsync, that should work. I hope :)